# Papa Parse incorect column type

Tags: javascript, papaparse

I have one column with for example 5/5 value and when i exporting this data to csv file result is date format (5-MAY).

How can i change column type in config object?

here is example data

```
var data = [{count:'5/5'},{count:'23/5'}];
```

Comment: Do you have "dynamicTyping" set to true? Otherwise, it shouldn't be doing automatic conversion - https://www.papaparse.com/docs#config